# С помощью какой диаграммы изобразить структуру XML/JSON-файла?

Tags: json, xml, диаграммы

Для изображения структуры, например, реляционных БД используются **ER-диаграммы**. Мне необходимо изобразить структуру XML или JSON-файла. Понятно, что оба файла имеют вид дерева. Но все же, есть ли какие-то *диаграммы* или *рекомендации* для изображения структуры данных файлов?

Comment: Нужно показывать структуру *любых* файлов xml/json или каких-то *конкретных*? Так-то да, сами по себе они иерархические, поэтому только дерево в общем случае подойдёт. Но если заранее известен набор данных (схема), то можно подобрать что-то получше: это может быть и таблица (DataGrid), и гистограмма, и пр.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю *ERwin Data Modeler*. С его помощью, можно очень глубоко и подробно отобразить структуру.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, он совсем для других целей предназначен.

Comment: Да, немного другая методология, но рискнуть можно. А Вы пробовали RationalRose, Umbrello, MS Visio?

Comment: Да, я с ними работал. Это среда разработки диаграмм. Меня интересует не это, а **как** именно изобразить данную среду. Инструменты разработки - дело второстепенное.